# Digital Uncertainty

Tags: statistics

**What am I doing?**

I am calculating wind velocity $v$ from the mean of n samples of differential pressure $\Delta P$ using the following formula:

$$v=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sqrt{\frac{2\Delta P_i}{\rho}}$$

Where $\rho$ is the air density that can be calculated using this formula:

$$\rho=\frac{1}{T}K$$

Where $T$ is temperature and $K$ is some non important constant containing barometric pressure, humidity and some other goodies.

**What am I trying to achieve?**

I have an example of how to calculate the uncertainty of the velocity due to the digital conversion of the temperature. But I don't fully understand it, hopefully someone in here can explain it?

**What have I done so far?**

This is how far I have gotten in understanding the example:

The wind velocitys sensitivity to changes in temperature can be calculated as:

$$\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{T}}=\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial\rho}\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial{T}}$$

The wind velocity can be written as:

$$v=C\frac{1}{\sqrt{\rho}}$$ 
where 
$$C=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sqrt{\Delta P_i}$$

Then:

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial\rho}=\frac{-C}{2\sqrt{\rho^3}}=\frac{-C}{2\sqrt{\rho^3}}\frac{\sqrt{\rho}}{\sqrt{\rho}}=\underline{\frac{-v}{2\rho}}$$

Next we calculate:

$$\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial T}=\frac{-K}{T^2}=\frac{-K}{T^2}\frac{T}{T}=\underline{\frac{-\rho}{T}}$$

Finaly we combine the two results and get the sensitivity value:

$$\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{T}}=\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial\rho}\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial{T}}=\underline{\underline{\frac{v}{2T}}}$$

Then the example starts to calculate some uncertainties: Assuming that the temperature is converted into a voltage from 0 to 10 V with 12 bit resolution then the sampled value could be off by the quantisation limit $q$:

$$q=\frac{1}{2}\frac{10V}{2^{12}}=0.00122V$$

Since there is a uniform distribution within that voltage interval the related standard uncertainty $u_T$ at a 95% confidence interval is:

$$u_T=\frac{q}{\sqrt{3}} = 0.000704V$$

From this point I don't understand the example anymore. It continues by saying that the temperature is assumed to be $15^oC$ and this correspondes to 7.6V this is equivalent to:

$$\frac{7.6V}{2q}=3113$$

Then the example states that this means that the uncertainty $u$ has to be less than:

$$u < \frac{u_T}{3113}=0.0000023V \tag1$$

Then it calculates the sensitivity value at 10 m/s as:

$$c_{10}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial T}=\frac{10\frac{m}{s}}{2*0.00244V}=2049 \tag2$$

Then the final uncertainty due to the digitisation of the measure temperature is concluded to be:

$$uc_{10}=0.004\frac{m}{s} \tag3$$

**My questions:**

1. Is equation (1) true and why?
2. In equation (2) shouldn't the inserted T be a temperature and not voltage?
3. In equation (3) is the unit really $\frac{m}{s}$?
4. Is there another way of calculating the uncertainty?

Thanks a big bunch!

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line of your analysis is to calculate a plausible interval within which the true velocity  may lie. If you know the resolution of your digital temperature meter, then if it reads, say, $76.1$ (hence a resolution of $0.1$), then the actual temperature will be between $76.05$ to $76.14$. These are the upper and lower bounds of what the temperature could be, correct? In that case, your uncertainty is just the largest and smallest velocity you can achieve when you vary the temperature between $76.05$ and $76.14$. (It will likely just be the endpoints of this range, but some formulas have internal maxima or minima.)